# JXBrowser navigator.languages always empty

Tags: java, javafx, jxbrowser

I'm trying to find out, how to set the navigator.languages in JXBrowser. The array is always empty and for the specific site I'm on with the JXBrowser, I need to have the navigator.languages to be set.

I added the flag "--lang=en" to chromium, I also did set

```
BrowserContextParams bcp = new BrowserContextParams(browserContextPath);
bcp.setAcceptLanguage("en-US");
```

But all these things seem to not change anything. Is that a general JXBrowser "thing" or "bug"? Or am I just missing something?

I would rather not intercept every request and try to add or inject navigator.languages manually.

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding [Chromium switch](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013081-chromium-language) seems to work properly and the `navigator.language` property is changed:

```
public class JxBrowserSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BrowserPreferences.setChromiumSwitches("--lang=zh-CN");

        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        browser.loadURL("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_nav_language");
    }
}
```

Output:
[image: navigator.language changed]

The `navigator.languages[0]` contains the same value in this case.

I have used JxBrowser 6.19.1 for checking this behavior.